# upgrade tailwind difficult referring file path, content variable

Tags: tailwind-css

```
module.exports = {
content: ["../../../../Views/**/*.cshtml"],
theme: {
    extend: {},
},
plugins: [],
}
```

I am not sure how to refer to all cshtml files so that tailwindcss is reflected.

error details: warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration

Comment: I found out the following, the content: ['path/'] described in tailwind.config.js must be in reference to the command-line path where you enter your command npx from.
if command line path is ~/desktop/username/folderabc, and if html paths are in ~/desktop/username/folderabc/src then the content: ['./src/**/*.{cshtml}']
this is the problem when we have multiple project folder in asp.net project, it was confusing where to run the npx command from